# Find out which DB Heroku is currently using

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I recently had a short term project served off of Heroku that approached 10,000 Postgres records and needed to be upgraded from hobby-dev to hobby-basic. Being new to Heroku, I did my best in finding out how to do so and followed heroku's upgrade using PG Backup guide. With a bit of trial and error, I thought I got it working. I erred on the side of caution and didn't do the last deletion of the old DB step. However, I soon got a message from Heroku telling me I've passed the 10,000 record limit. I went to my Heroku dashboard and checked out the DB size. It doesn't look like the Hobby-Basic DB had anything stored in it. I waited a couple weeks and checked again, thinking it may have been a realtime updating issue. Still no tables in the new Hobby-Basic DB.

So my question is, is there a way for me to find out which DB my Heroku app is set up to use currently? How do I force it to switch to a different DB in my app?

This is the guide I followed to upgrade from Hobby-Dev to Basic: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrade-heroku-postgres-with-pgbackups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably your app is reading from the environment variable `DATABASE_URL`.  If you have multiple database then you should also have other environment variables like `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_(color)`.  You can access those environment variables from within your app to inspect the configured database information, and you can change them in the Heroku panel.  If you change `DATABASE_URL` to one of the values of `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_(color)`, then your app should pick up on that and switch to the different database.  You can also edit your configuration and access another environment variable while bypassing DATABASE_URL entirely.

Comment: I don't remember ever explicitly setting a DATABASE_URL. I simply deployed using the method in the Hartl Rails Tutorial: http://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning#sec-deploying . The Heroku dashboard does indeed show HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_(color) for the different DB's I have installed. Is there a simple terminal command I can use to verify which one my Heroku app is currently using?

Comment: Heroku automatically configures `DATABASE_URL` and the other `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL...` variables when you add a database to your app.  I believe it may even automatically add a database to your app in some cases.  Inspect your environment with `heroku config` or the heroku app settings panel.

Comment: `heroku config` and `heroku pg` will both be useful for inspecting the app from the command line.

Comment: Perfect, heroku config was exactly what I was looking for. It looks like DATABASE_URL matches the URL for HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_NAVY_URL (my hobby-dev DB). So it looks like it indeed never cloned to my Hobby-Basic and switched over to it. Thanks for the help!